# Can I initialize Selenium web driver with a static instance of HTML page residing on my computer

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am very new to selenium and what I am asking may not make sense. I am doing this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_url);
```

I know this method takes in a URL and URL is different than file location. I am wondering if there is a way to initalize selenium webdriver and use it to access DOM of a static HTML webpage residing on my local hard drive.

Comment: URL = uniform resource locator.  URLs can absolutely point to file paths as long as they are in the proper format.  Usually something along the lines of file:///C:/some/path/to/the/file.html or equivalent for the particular OS. 

Now whether or not Selenium supports that, i do not know, though it should if it supports proper URLs

Comment: @MikeMcMahon: *file///...* works with chrome webdriver (and I assume with the other browser implementations) but did not work for me with PhantomJS.

Answer (score 2):

The truth is that Selenium doesn't care. Your browser opens the file, Selenium only sees what the browser sees. So yes, you can use Selenium on local files, just give it the right URL that will open in your favourite browser.